# Exercise with maximum and minimum between real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

Let $a, b, \alpha, \beta>1$ be four real numbers. Consider
$$\max\lbrace a^{-\alpha}, b^{-\beta}\rbrace.$$
I am looking for the right quantity C such that
$$\max\lbrace a^{-\alpha}, b^{-\beta}\rbrace\cdot C =1.$$
I guess that it is $\min\lbrace a^{\alpha}, b^{\beta}\rbrace$, but I don’t know how to prove it.

Could anyone please tell me if it is true and help me to prove it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u$ and $v$ be positive real numbers. Then $\max(u,v)^{-1}=\min(u^{-1},v^{-1})$.
This is since if say $u<v$ then $\max(u,v)=v$ and $\min(u^{-1},v^{-1})=v^{-1}$
etc.

Comment: thank you for the answer. So, I found the correct value for C?

Comment: Yes, you did. @C.Bishop

Comment: Thank you very much @Angina

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\max(a^{-\alpha},b^{-\beta})=a^{-\alpha}$ then $C=a^{\alpha}$.

Since $a^{-\alpha}\geq b^{-\beta}$ it follows $a^{\alpha}\leq b^{\beta}$.

For the case $\max(a^{-\alpha},b^{-\beta})=b^{-\beta}$ just repeat above method.

You are right! ;-)